# Why does JMeter always have only one thread

Tags: jmeter

I deployed JMeter (v5.6.2) on my Centos7 (8C16G) and tried to do some tests with it.

I created a Thread Group, which contains a HTTP request.

However, it seems that the process of JMeter always has only one thread no matter how I configure it.

The Thread Group is configurable with three config variables: Number of Threads (users), Ramp-up period and Loop Count/Infinite.

I've tried to configure them to 50, 5 and Infinite. But it still has only one thread. Because `cat /proc/<pid>/status` always shows me `Threads: 1`.

Comment: What does jstack show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't be the case, Java threads should map 1:1 to POSIX threads (unless you're using custom JMeter utilizing [project Loom](https://openjdk.org/projects/loom/) features) plus Java itself will run some internal threads. Anyway I cannot reproduce your issue, maybe your `<pid>` is wrong?

[image]

Also be aware that according to [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-memory-profiling) article you should always be using the latest version of JMeter so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.6.3](https://lists.apache.org/thread/o906of55x1n8z2zm8fyj3w9k3lqf8y0c) (or whatever is the latest stable version which is available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page)

Comment: Ohh, you are right, `<pid>` was wrong... I executed the command `bin/jmeter` to start the JMeter, which is a script. The real process is not this one. `ps aux | grep java` could find the real JMeter process.